# How to securely store AWS service ids for iOS?

Tags: ios, security, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-iam

I'm developing an iOS app that uses Cognito User Pools / Federated Identities, Mobile Analytics, and S3 to manage various features of the app, and recently I have become concerned for the security of these features. I already use IAM roles to control the services unauthenticated vs authenticated users have access to, but most of these services use strings (e.g. user pool app client id or user pool app client secret for User Pools, or app id for Mobile Analytics) to give the app access to that service.

What are the best practices to securely store these strings on the device to be used when necessary? Is it even necessary to secure these strings since the app is using IAM roles?

If it is necessary to securely store the strings, I have read that using the CommonCrypto library to encrypt strings before putting them in the keychain is best, but I'm not sure what key to use for encryption since my user needs unauthenticated access to those services. Any advice would be tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem to any mobile app. If someone really wants to, it's not difficult to decompile the app and scrape the keys from it. It's great that you are using IAM roles to restrict feature usage. This will limit the blast radius of attackers, but not necessarily prevent them.

Wth user pools you also get a globally unique identifier which can be used with IAM to restrict what S3 you can use key pre-fixes (which act similar to folders) to limit the objects that users can access to pre-fixes with their unique identifier. You can refer to https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies (Using user pools as the provider, which will use the identity id as the prefix). Depending on how you structure your app you could use this so each user can only modify their own objects. I don't think Analytics has any way of restricting like this... because it wouldn't really make sense for it.

As far as securing your ID's there are things you can do to help mitigate, but there is no fool proof way to prevent someone taking it. You could for instance have the app make a call to your server for the ID... but then an attacker could just call the server. You could encrypt it, which might make it more difficult for an attacker to get, but you have to keep the key somewhere and if the app could get it so could someone who decompiles the app. Unless your app users get some sort of password from outside the app and put it in there isn't a complete way to lock it against attackers.

Hope this helps.